# Me da error al separa el main porque no reconoce las variables

Tags: java

Buenas tengo que hacer el siguiente ejercicio. Con dos hilos, incrementa un entero compartido en uno repetidamente, con sincronización, 1 000 000 de veces (500 000 cada uno) e imprime el resultado al final del programa.
Mas o menos he encntrado la solucion pero esta todo metido dentro de una clase runable y no separa el main en otra clase. Cuando lo inteto hacer me da error a ver si me podeis ayudar a separlo correctamente.

esta es la clase de los Hilos

```
public class Hilos implements Runnable {

    private static final int NUM_THREADS = 2;
    private static final int NUM_INCREMENTS = 1000000;
    private Variable counter;

    public Hilos(Variable counter) {
        this.counter = counter;
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i=0; i<NUM_INCREMENTS; ++i) {
            counter.incrementCount();
        }
    }

}
```

entiendo que esta parte es el main

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
            Thread[] threads = new Thread[NUM_THREADS];
            Variable counter = new Variable();

            for (int i=0; i<NUM_THREADS; ++i) {
                threads[i] = new Thread(new Hilos(counter));
                threads[i].start();
            }

            for (int i=0; i<NUM_THREADS; ++i) {
                threads[i].join();
            }

            System.out.println("total count = " + counter.getCount() + " vs. expected = " + (NUM_THREADS * NUM_INCREMENTS));
        }
```

Esta la Variable que usamos es un contador

```
public class Variable {

    private int count = 0;

    public int getCount() {
        return count ;
    }


    public synchronized void incrementCount() {
        ++count;
    }

}
```

Comment: Qué error te da? Podrías copartir el código con el `main()` separado para entender mejor que puede estar ocurriendo?

Comment: NUM_THREADS y NUM_INCREMENTS no las reconoce

Comment: vale modifico y pongo el main aparte o como creo que va

Comment: Y.. esas variables donde es que estan definidas?

Comment: es un ejercicio que me ha mandado el profesor para resolver uno que no se hacer porque es pareceido y la idea es separalo para entenederlo

Answer (score 4):

Las variables por lo visto están dentro de otra clase (`Hilos`) diferente a donde se encuentra tu método `main`, por lo mismo, para que éstas puedan ser usadas dentro del método `main`, se debe de importar la clase correspondiente.

Pero dentro de `Hilos`, tus variables `NUM_THREADS` y `NUM_INCREMENTS` son ***privadas***, por lo mismo al querer usarlas en el `main`, te da ese error, aunque importes todo lo de `Hilos`.

Por lo mismo tendrías que:

1. Cambiar el modificador de acceso a `public` para ambas, así serán accesibles desde fuera de la clase con `Hilos.NUM_THREADS`.

```java
public static final int NUM_THREADS = 2;
public static final int NUM_INCREMENTS = 1000000;
```

2. Si es que quisieras mantenerlas privadas por cualquier motivo, puedes crear unos métodos `get` para cada variable.

---

Para la variable de numero de hilos podrías crear un método para que retorne solo este atributo, ya sea `NUM_THREADS` o `NUM_INCREMENTS`

```
public int devuelveNumThreads(){
        return NUM_THREADS;
}
//lo mismo para NUM_INCREMENTS
```

Resultado cuando llamas al método:

> 2

Otra opción es iniciar una variable dentro del método `main` y usarla.

```
private int numero_hilos = 2;
```

o

```
private int numero_hilos = devuelveNumThreads;
```

[Modificadores de acceso en JAVA](https://www.aprenderaprogramar.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=665:public-private-y-protected-javatipos-de-modificadores-de-acceso-visibilidad-en-clases-subclases-cu00693b&catid=68&Itemid=188)

Answer (score 1):

Primeramente no puedes leer las variables estáticas desde la clase `Hilos` ya que tienen el modificador `private` , para que sean leídas en otra clase usa `public`:

```
   public static final int NUM_THREADS = 2;
   public static final int NUM_INCREMENTS = 1000000;
```

De esta forma haciendo referencia a la clase que define las variables (`Hilos.NUM_THREADS` y `Hilos.NUM_INCREMENTS`) puedes obtener su valor en tu clase principal.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Thread[] threads = new Thread[Hilos.NUM_THREADS];
        Variable counter = new Variable();

        for (int i=0; i<Hilos.NUM_THREADS; ++i) {
            threads[i] = new Thread(new Hilos(counter));
            threads[i].start();
        }

        for (int i=0; i<Hilos.NUM_THREADS; ++i) {
            threads[i].join();
        }

        System.out.println("total count = " + counter.getCount() + " vs. expected = " + (Hilos.NUM_THREADS * Hilos.NUM_INCREMENTS));

}
```